# add a command to webpack to preprocess the js

Tags: webpack

I have `preprocess bundle.js . -FULL=true > bundle.full.js`  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/preprocessor) to run the preprocessing of the javascript. My webpack.config.js is below,

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var PROD = JSON.parse(process.env.PROD_ENV || '0');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./bootstrap.js",
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: PROD ? 'bundle.min.js' : 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: PROD ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false }
        })
    ] : [],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    }
};
```

How can I add my preprocess command to the config to make it run automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `preprocess-loader`

`npm install preprocess-loader --save-dev`

And change your `webpack.config.js` to:

    `module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.css$/, 
            loader: "style!css!preprocess?+FULL"
        }]
    }`

For more info, check out:

- preprocess-loader on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preprocess-loader)
- preprocess-loader on [github](https://github.com/dearrrfish/preprocess-loader)